# Sails custom routing

Tags: sails.js

Following are my custom routes for an application. Is there a better way or organizing them ? I hate to create set of custom routes whenever new module gets added. I would ideally like to do way without defining any one of them. As my urls run few level deep, I am not to take advantage of default Controller/Action/:id routing.

Does adding of lot of custom routes affect app performance ? Help appreciated.

```
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/new'         : 'LocationController.equipmentNew',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/create'      : 'LocationController.equipmentCreate',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/edit/:id'    : 'LocationController.equipmentEdit',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/update/:id'  : 'LocationController.equipmentUpdate',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/list'        : 'LocationController.equipmentList',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/show/:id'    : 'LocationController.equipmentShow',
'get /location/:locationId/equipment/delete/:id'  : 'LocationController.equipmentDelete',

'get /location/:locationId/employee/new'          : 'LocationController.employeeNew',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/create'       : 'LocationController.employeeCreate',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/edit/:id'     : 'LocationController.employeeEdit',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/update/:id'   : 'LocationController.employeeUpdate',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/list'         : 'LocationController.employeeList',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/show/:id'     : 'LocationController.employeeShow',
'get /location/:locationId/employee/delete/:id'   : 'LocationController.employeeDelete',

'get /location/:locationId/manager/new'           : 'LocationController.managerNew',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/create'        : 'LocationController.managerCreate',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/edit/:id'      : 'LocationController.managerEdit',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/update/:id'    : 'LocationController.managerUpdate',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/list'          : 'LocationController.managerList',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/show/:id'      : 'LocationController.managerShow',
'get /location/:locationId/manager/delete/:id'    : 'LocationController.managerDelete',
'get /location/:locationId/participate'           : 'LocationController.participate',
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but you'll have to write your own request router using express middleware.

In SailsJS every [policy](http://www.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies) is a middleware. You can pass custom parameters together with controller and action name in URL and call related controller action directly from the policy.

First, you'll need to define routes for actions with and without :id parameter

*config/routes.js*

```
/locations/:locationId/:controller/:action : { policy: 'router' }
/locations/:locationId/:controller/:action/:id : { policy: 'router' }
```

Next, you'll need to write code for redirecting request to controllers and actions depending on URL parameters.

*api/policies/router.js*

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var controller = req.param('controller');
    var action = req.param('action');
    sails.controllers[controller][action](req, res);
};
```

Then, you can define your contollers in separate files:

*api/controllers/EmployeeController.js & api/controllers/EquipmentController.js*

```
module.exports = {
    new: function(req, res) {
        var params = req.params.all();
        // ...
    },
    // ... other actions
};
```

**Important:** Remember to protect actions you don't want to expose!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your API could use some refactoring.  You have four models (`Equipment`, `Employee`, `Manager` and `Location`), but you're namespacing them all under `location` in your API.  Instead, they could all be first-level endpoints, allowing you to use Sails' [blueprints](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) to handle routing for you.  For example, if you removed *all* of those custom routes, and created four controllers in your **api/controllers** folder:

- EquipmentController.js
- EmployeeController.js
- ManagerController.js
- LocationController.js

and four models in your **api/models** folder:

- Equipment.js
- Employee.js
- Manager.js
- Location.js

then without doing any work at all, when you lift Sails you'll be able to do things like

- `GET /manager?location=5` to list all managers at location 5
- `POST /equipment` to create a new piece of equipment
- `PUT /employee/123` to update employee 123

Promoting everything to the first level and then using queries like `?location=5` to filter output makes everything a lot clearer.

If you're concerned that this allows one to view *all employees* across locations, or if some users should only be able to view some locations, you can control this with [policies](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies), which are intended precisely for access control.  Simply add a policy that ensures that a location is set in the params for every "get managers" call, or one that checks that the currently logged-in user is authorized to view the location they're attempting to access.